# Managing SQLite Database Subset Versions

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

Our research team has an internal sqlite database with many thousands of records, many of which are proprietary and thus private. We also have a published version of the database which contains a subset of the data: two hundred records. I'm trying to decide the best way to keep track of which records have been published and thinking ahead of how I can track which are published in version 1, 2, 3, etc. Ideally, I would be able to grab all records with a specific version number or lower to create a publishable subset of the database.

Our team has a two ideas:

1. add a new table in the database that keeps track of the primary key, table name, and release number for all published data,
2. add a new column for each table, with default value NULL, that has the release number for records that have been published

Is there any accepted method on how to go about doing this? 
I tried searching for best practices, but this sounds like a bit of a unique scenario.

Comment: Why you are using  the mysql tag ?  .please remove the unsed tag ..

Comment: I think both options are OK. I would choose the one with the least amount of overhead for you.

Answer (score 1):

Option 2 will likely be the easiest to implement, and can be quickly indexed - however you will be potentially denormalizing the data.

Option 1 would be the preferred option for a normalised data-structure, but will require a little bit more work when writing the SQL.

I'd be tempted to go for option 1.

This way the original data will be unaffected, especially if you decide that the subset is no longer required in the future (you won't have a redundant column).

While you could edit the table easily enough - it's generally not a good idea to noodle with production 'live' data.

That said - both options are perfectly acceptable.